# In RxJs, what are the examples of Hot and Cold Observable operators?

Tags: rxjs, rxjs-observables

Is there a list to differentiate them?
I have tried using some of them and was thinking if there is a list for me to check whether I am using the Hot or Cold Observable operator.

Comment: What do you mean with “hot / cold operators”? I am aware of hot/cold Observables but not of hot/cold operators.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I have used some operators(not sure if this is the correct term for this) like:
of(),
from(),
fromEvent(),
etc..